# manually validate/accept users flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

so im building an app which has 2 users(staff and student) and the staff  must accept/verify users manually. thereby when the student registers/signs up this would show up as a request on the staff side then after the staff accepts or rejects the request which allows the studentto enter the app. i've already coded the sign-in sign up pages which looks very similar to [this](https://github.com/Lama-Alsaif/makken/blob/main/lib/lana/student/DashboardPages/BrailleConversionRequestPage.dart) using firestore authentication.

the only solution i could think of is adding the user sign up info as a request and saving it under a firestore collection("registration requests") i though about how the password field might be an issue but i found that people used the flutter_string_encryption package to save the password as a .doc field. then when the staff accepts the request the method/ function `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)` would be called but i don't know if this is the "correct" way of achieving this.honestly i have no idea how to tackle this problem. is there is any resource that tackle the same issue or any other way this could be archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a system whereby any student can create an account using `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` but the account has an associated flag/boolean which prevents them from viewing content until it is true.

E.g

1. Student creates account using `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.
2. Upon creating new user, create a FireStore document containing a boolean set to false if the account is unverified.
3. Allow teachers to alter the FireStore record for students and change the boolean value to true upon verification.
4. Dynamically display content to users based on wether the boolean in their FireStore record is set to true or false.

If this sounds feasible, I can provide more detail on the specific code if you're not familiar with the packages.

Comment: I Implemented the same in one of my web apps as what you suggested and it works great. Adding upon what you said to point 3 you can get details of the unregistered students using a query. And Also use firestore rules to ensure that unregistered students are not getting access to info they are not supposed to using a get request to their Boolean value.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works well, and great addition regarding the query and FireStore rules. This seems to be a fairly simple but effective way of achieving the desired functionality.

Comment: thank you i think i can defiantly apply this easily to my app. but if you can expand more on the implementation and packages

Comment: You will need the following packages:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth
https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

For step 2, create a firestore collection in the firebase console such as 'verified'. Then you can use FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('verified').doc().set() to create a document for each user containing information on wether they are verified or not and wether they are a teacher or student. 

For step 4 you can use a FutureBuilder that fetches information from Firestore about the user's verification status and display different screens based on the result